# how to use ZoomingPDFViewer?

Tags: ios, pdf, viewer

I downloaded the following code to implement a PDF page flipper from the apple ios developer library : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html

I copied the 2 uiviewcontrollers into my own storyboard and i added all the classes except the appdelegate. Then, in one of my previous uiviewcontrollers, i wrote :

```
RootViewController *page = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:page animated:YES];
```

but this line returns nil instead of an instance of DataViewController :

```
DataViewController *dataViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DataViewController"];
```

Though I'm sure i set the storyboard ID to DataView Controller...
Thanks for your help !

Comment: The link you provided only references the header file, this is not useful by itself. Plenty of tutorials out there, Apples one is good https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html (read it all) otherwise have you seen tried this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fs-PZvaa47s

Comment: Yes, the reference pointed to a header file but it's the same as your link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: What I would like to know is whether I forgot something when I copied/pasted the UIViewControllers in my own storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone encounters the same problem , here is what I did wrong : I copied/pasted the code but I was not careful about a line in the code which used

```
self.storyboard
```

You have to replace it by :

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
```

where "Main" must be replaced by the name of your storyboard.